# Counting nodes on the fly

Tags: xml, xslt, variables, count, nodes

I'm trying to count nodes in an XML document like the one below without knowing the names of the nodes beforehand:

```
<library>
<book>1</book>
<book>2</book>
<magazine>1</magazine>
<magazine>2</magazine>
<magazine>3</magazine>
</library>
```

I'm trying do it this way (and variants of this) but not getting anywhere:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:variable name="e" select="name()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count(../$e)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks Dimitre, that did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(//*[name() = name(current())]
```

Because this XPath expression starts with the `//` pseudo-operator, it may be very inefficient (slow).

**Better use keys**. Define:

```
<xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name()"/>
```

**and in your code use it like this**:

```
count(key('kElemByName', name(current())))
```

Comment: @GavinSerra: You are welcome. Here at SO the official form of expressing gratitude is to accept the best answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to this answer). Please, consider doing so.

Comment: sorry - browser wouldn't let me until now